# Gstreamer-1.2.2 : simple pipeline with decklinksink doesn't output raw video

Tags: testing, gstreamer, pipeline

I am having problems with a very simple pipeline with decklinksink in it. I can output the audio but no the video. I have Gstreamer-1.2.2 with all plugins included (bad, good, ugly, base, libav).

Simple Pipeline : (only video)
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! decklinksink mode=2
Observation : No video

I tried with autovideosink and it works well.

Simple Pipeline : (video + audio)
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! decklinksink mode=2 name=sink audiotestsrc ! sink.
Observation : Still no video, only audio

That worked well in the 0.10v. If you guys got any advance or help.
Thanks & Regards
Tom

Comment: Try
(1.) gst-inspect decklinksink     (2.) export GST_DEBUG=*:5  export GST_DEBUG_FILE=<some location> try to figure then  (3.) Check if libDeckLinkAPI.so is present

Comment: (1.) gst-inspect-1.0 decklinksink -> http://pastebin.com/ZN7MhA4M (2.) GST_DEBUG=5 -> http://pastebin.com/x2A9QxVM

Comment: Sorry, didn't finish my edit sooner. Reposted. (1.) gst-inspect-1.0 decklinksink -> http://pastebin.com/ZN7MhA4M (2.) GST_DEBUG=5 -> http://pastebin.com/x2A9QxVM (3.) locate libDeckLinkAPI -> /usr/lib/libDeckLinkAPI.so   I think that maybe decklinksink needs an upgrade since hasn't change since December for the intersect problem well it's just a suggestion. Any help or advance are welcome. Regards, Tom